# How can I get a variable's address inside kernel?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel

Currently, I want to get the address of runqueues, which is a variable in the kernel and not planned to be visible to modules or code outside.

I can get the address of runqueues by checking /proc/kallsyms. But this address is not the real address because of the ASLR.

I really do not want to change kernel so I decide to insert a module.
Does anyone know how to get the address of the variable inside the kernel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your Queries :-

> I want to get the address of runqueues, which is a variable in the
>   kernel?

runqueue is represented by struct runqueue, that is a core data structure in the scheduler instead of variable.

> I can get the address of runqueues by checking /proc/kallsyms.

There are some macros are used to obtain the runqueue associated with a given processor or process. from this macro we are getting the base address of array of runqueue structure and CPU id. I believe you can not retrieve the runqueue info from /proc/kallsysm.

1. The macro cpu_rq(processor) returns a pointer to the runqueue associated with the given processor.
2. The macro this_rq() returns the runqueue of the current processor;
3. The macro task_rq(task) returns a pointer to the runqueue on
   which the given task is queued.

So, I think to get the info of all runqueue, you have make multi-threading application and dedicate each thread to specific CPU (set cpu affinity).

Comment: My problem is I cannot directly use these functions you mentioned. These functions finally use runqueues' address to return a specific runqueue.